# Defining a global variable to run in a defined PYTHON

Tags: python

So i'm writing an RPG text based game for a school assignment although i'm having troubles with making a global variable for the player health as i have written the battle logic within a defined function. At the moment, each time the function plays through it sets the playerHealth to 100 although i want it to make the playerHealth equal to the last time it was modified. For example: if i went into a battle and lost 10 health making my health 90, the next time i battle it would be set to 90 health.

```
def battle():
  playerHealth = 100
  enemyHealth = 20


  while enemyHealth > 0:

  attack = input('Melee or Ranged Attack?\n> ').lower()
  if attack[0] == 'm':
      chance = random.randint(0,2)
      if chance == 0:
          print('***********')
          print('You missed!')
          print('***********')
          print('You receive 4 damage')
          playerHealth -= 4
          print('')
          print('Player Health = ' + str(playerHealth))

      else:
          print('You hit the enemy, also causing damage to yourself')
          print('Enemy receives 3 damage')
          print('Player receives 1 damage')
          enemyHealth -= 4
          playerHealth -= 1
          print('')
          print('Enemy Health = ' + str(enemyHealth))
          print('Player Health = ' + str(playerHealth))

  elif attack[0] == 'r':
      chance = random.randint(0,2)
      if chance == 0:
          print('***********')
          print('You missed!')
          print('***********')
          print('The enemy attacks you causing 3 damage')
          playerHealth -= 3
          print('')
          print('Player Health = ' + str(playerHealth))

      else:
          print('-----------')
          print('Direct hit!')
          print('-----------')
          print('Enemy receives 2 damage')
          enemyHealth -= 2
          print('')
          print('Enemy Health = ' + str(enemyHealth))

print('---------------------')           
print('You killed the enemy!') 
print('---------------------')
```

So then afterwards i would use:

```
if "enemy" in deadZone[currentArea1]:
  battle()
```

Comment: How/where did you define `deadZone`?  That looks like it is a global.

Comment: Put the variable outside the function?

Comment: deadZone is already a dictionary map, and moving the variable outside the function displays "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playerHealth' referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize it outside the function, pass it to the function, and have the function return it.

```
def battle(playerHealth):
    ...
    return playerHealth

...

if "enemy" in deadZone[currentArea1]:
    playerHealth = battle(playerHealth)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def battle(player_health, enemy_health):
    ...
    ...
    return player_health, enemy_health


player_health, enemy_health = battle(100, 20)
```